# pumpevents - customized look and feel java taking too much system resources

Tags: java, performance, events, resources, message-pump

I make my own GUI [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637221/over-ride-default-look-and-feel-java) but system is taking too much resources on further looking into the issue i have found that java pumpevents method is talking too much time. 
Any resolutions ????
pump events more detail [pump event detail](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/java/awt/EventDispatchThread.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are too many objects instantiating in GUI that you have provided.
Make some fields static and check before creating that do they already exists...if..then... [Singleton Concept].