# background color for JTab

Tags: swing

I'm trying to set the background color for a JTab. I can set it and see the new color if I am not on that particular tab. If I am on that tab I don't see the color. I think its because it overwrites the background color with the 'selected' color since we've selected that tab.

What can I do? Thank you very much!!

Comment: what do you mean by "JTab" - that's not a class in core Swing ...

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the JTabbedPane:

```
UIManager.put("TabbedPane.selected", YOUR_COLOR)
```

Also see: [Override default look and feel Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637221/override-default-look-and-feel-java)

Comment: Does this take affect for that particular tab or all of the tabs? I want to it just for certain tabs.

Comment: Setting the value in the UIManager will do it for the entire application.  The link has another way to customize the entire app.  For a single tab, you can call setUI on it and build your own UI painter: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7859035/jtabbedpane-customize-tab-look, google around there's a lot of stuff out there about this idea.